# How do I receive a single instance of a button press in GLFW?

Tags: c++, opengl, input, glfw

I have a basic camera and movement system in my game, and would like to press escape to halt all movement/camera motion, and allow the user control of their mouse cursor.

When pressing escape however, it takes multiple inputs (from the time that the button is actually down), and registers all of them.

My code switches a boolean `looking` when escape is pressed, and I suspect the problem is that looking is switched multiple times per escape press.
Code:

```cpp
bool looking = true;

/* Loop until the user closes the window */
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
{
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS)
    {
        looking = !looking;
        std::cout << looking << std::endl;
    }
    // ...
}
```

The `cout` call gives the following output after one press:

```
0
1
0
1
0
1
0
```

The expected output is a single boolean output when escape is pressed (initially this would be 0, and would alternate with successive presses).

Is there a better function call than `glfwGetKey()` for specifically detecting a single button press?

Comment: Use the [key callback function](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/input_guide.html#input_keyboard) which allows you to respond to the key being released.